# Terminal permission denied with C program on MacBook Pro

Tags: c

When I am going to run "C" project using code block on My Mac then every time get same message that is Terminal Permission denied. Please help someone to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: Try putting a period in front of the path of the executable you're running.

Comment: Included image in body of question.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `chmod +x path_to_your_file` to give the file execution rights. Then run it again